# iconv() Vs. utf8_encode()

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

when you have a charset different of UTF-8 and you need to put it on JSON format to migrate it to a DB, there are two methods that can be used in PHP, calling  utf8_encode() and iconv(). I would like to know which one have better performance, and when is convenient to use one or another.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> when you have a charset different of UTF-8

Nope - `utf8_encode()` is suitable **only** for converting a ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8. Iconv provides a vast number of source and target encodings.

Re performance, I have no idea how `utf8_encode()` works internally  and what libraries it uses, but my prediction is there won't be much of a difference - at least not on "normal" amounts of data in the bytes or kilobytes. If in doubt, do a benchmark.

I tend to use `iconv()` because it's clearer that there is a conversion from character set A to character set B.

Also, `iconv()` provides more detailed control on what to do when it encounters invalid data. Adding `//IGNORE` to the target character set will cause it to silently drop invalid characters. This may be helpful in certain situations.

Comment: also you can use //trasnlit to generate this type of conversion u\00f, that java decode automatically to ISO-8859-1. but I'm not sure if the same is going to happen if there are different charsets that got encoded to utf-8.

Comment: Note that PHP >= 5.4.0 will now fail on invalid characters, even with the `//IGNORE` flag: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61484

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to write your own function.
It will be 2-3 lines long and it will be better than struggling with locale, iconv etc. issues.

For example:
[Fix Turkish Charset Issue Html / PHP (iconv?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122940/fix-turkish-charset-issue-html-php-iconv/9758237#9758237)

Comment: And what if the author wants an approach where he doesn't know all the possible input characters?