# PHP MS-SQL 2008 Characters Proplem

Tags: php

while i am querying from mssql server 2008 with php codes, Turkish characters are not supported. I made the default character set to UTF8 but still it doesn't work. Your kind help will be higly appreciated.
Regards,

We have problem with turkish characters as follows:  ığüşiöç IĞÜŞİÖÇ

Comment: Please post your query!

Comment: What database driver/extension are you using? `mssql_*`, `pdo_dblib` or `pdo_sqlsrv`?

Comment: @Khanh Tran  me use sql code : select * from tbstok

Comment: <?php
$serverName = "192.168.2.98";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxx", "UID"=>"xxx", "PWD"=>"xxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo );
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "select * from tbstok";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) )
  {
?>

Comment: Try this one: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122940/fix-turkish-charset-issue-html-php-iconv/9758237#9758237)